# Deskband and DPI Scaling?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

Is there a way to get a deskband DLL that is already marked PerMonitor and PerMonitorV2 aware to get the WM_DPICHANGED message?   It doesn't seem to be sent or is there another method that should be used for deskbands (system tray and time/date seems to scale so must be a way to get it)?  Using Win10 1909 x64.

TIA!!

Comment: If you open a hidden top-level window it should be able to receive this message.

Comment: Well, I just ended up for now checking if DPI changed on GetBandInfo() since those are sent on the DPI change.